# C: Maintaining N simultaneous pthreads at a time for M>>N independent calculations

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a problem that requires me to execute a particular calculation of variable length a large number of times (typically > 10^8) and I have a small number of processors  (<=16) to run it on.  The simplified code below successfully creates pthreads in batches of NTHREADS at a time, but it has the deficiency that everything else pauses until the slowest thread in each batch completes.  Since the slowest thread can occasionally be 10-100 times slower than the fastest thread, this means processors may be idle for a large fraction of the time, on average.

What I would like to do is keep all processors busy by creating a new pthread each time one terminates.  I could easily do this if there were a way to retrieve the current number of active pthreads, but I haven't found a way to do that.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct arg_struct {
  double x ;
  double y ;
};

int nloops = 0 ;  // initialize loop counter

void process(struct arg_struct  *args)
{
  int thisloop ;

  float x,y ;
  x = args->x ; y = args->y ;
  free(args) ;  // we're done with passed arguments

  nloops++ ;  // increment global counter 
  thisloop = nloops ;  // capture current loop  number

  sleep(11-nloops) ;  // variable delay
  printf("thisloop = %d   threadID = %d args = %.1f %.1f\n", thisloop,  (int) pthread_self(), x, y) ;

  pthread_exit(NULL); // exit thread
}

int main()
{
  const int MINLOOPS = 10 ;  // total number of loops to execute
  const int MAXTHREADS = 4 ;  // maximum number of threads at any one time

  int N, remaining ;
  pthread_t tid[MAXTHREADS];

  while (1)
    {
      remaining = MINLOOPS - nloops ;
      if (remaining == 0) break ;
      if (remaining < MAXTHREADS)
        N = remaining;
      else
        N = MAXTHREADS;

      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  // create a set of simultaneous threads

        struct arg_struct *args = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));  // initialize arguments
        args->x = i;  args->y = -i ;

        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, (void *) process,  (void *) args ) ;  
        printf("Created thread %d\n", (int) tid[i]) ;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // wait until all threads in current loop have completed 
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Created thread 216977408
Created thread 217513984
Created thread 218050560
Created thread 218587136
thisloop = 4   threadID = 218587136 args = 3.0 -3.0
thisloop = 3   threadID = 218050560 args = 2.0 -2.0
thisloop = 2   threadID = 217513984 args = 1.0 -1.0
thisloop = 1   threadID = 216977408 args = 0.0 0.0
Created thread 216977408
Created thread 217513984
Created thread 218050560
Created thread 218587136
thisloop = 8   threadID = 218050560 args = 2.0 -2.0
thisloop = 7   threadID = 218587136 args = 3.0 -3.0
thisloop = 6   threadID = 217513984 args = 1.0 -1.0
thisloop = 5   threadID = 216977408 args = 0.0 0.0
Created thread 216977408
Created thread 217513984
thisloop = 10   threadID = 217513984 args = 1.0 -1.0
thisloop = 9   threadID = 216977408 args = 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: You are describing a _thread pool_.  Usually, instead of creating and destroying threads, you will create them all at once and then use some sort of queue to distribute work amongst them.  Some technologies will do this for you at compile-time (_e.g._ OpenMP).

Comment: See my proposed solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my question, I worked out what seems to be an acceptable, if possibly naive, solution (before I knew that the best approach is a thread pool; see paddy's comment above).  It basically requires some bookkeeping, including the passing of additional variables to the threaded process.  Here's what I came up with:

```
struct arg_struct {
  double x ;
  double y ;
  int ithread ;
  int loopno ;
};

const int MINLOOPS = 10 ;  // total number of loops to execute
const int MAXTHREADS = 4 ;  // maximum number of threads at any one time
pthread_t tid[MAXTHREADS] ; // table of active threads

int loopno = 0 ;  // initialize loop counter
int nthreads = 0 ; // current number of active threads

void process(struct arg_struct  *args)
{
  int loopno,ithread ;
  float x,y ;
  x = args->x ; y = args->y ; ithread = args->ithread ; loopno = args->loopno ;
  free(args) ;  // we're done with passed arguments

  sleep(MINLOOPS-loopno+1) ;  // variable delay
  printf("thisloop = %d   threadID = %d args = %.1f %.1f ithread = %d\n", loopno,  (int) pthread_self(), x, y, ithread) ;

  nthreads-- ;   // done with current thread
  tid[ithread] = 0 ;
  pthread_exit(NULL); // exit thread
}

int main()
{
  int ithread ;

  for (ithread=0; ithread<MAXTHREADS; ithread++) tid[ithread] = 0 ;  // initialize thread table

  while (loopno < MINLOOPS)
    {
      if (nthreads < MAXTHREADS) {  // check whether new thread needed
        for (int ith=0; ith<MAXTHREADS; ith++)  // find empty table entry
          {
            if (tid[ith] == 0) {
              ithread = ith ;
              break ;
            }
          }

        struct arg_struct *args = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));  // initialize arguments

        loopno++ ;
        args->x = loopno;  args->y = -loopno ; args->ithread = ithread ; args->loopno = loopno ;
        pthread_create(&tid[ithread], NULL, (void *) process,  (void *) args ) ;  
        nthreads++ ;
        printf("Created thread %d\n", (int) tid[ithread]) ;
      }
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < MAXTHREADS; i++) // wait until remaining threads have completed 
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL) ;

}
```

The output is then:

```
Created thread 82550784
Created thread 83087360
Created thread 83623936
Created thread 84160512
thisloop = 4   threadID = 84160512 args = 4.0 -4.0 ithread = 3
Created thread 84697088
thisloop = 3   threadID = 83623936 args = 3.0 -3.0 ithread = 2
Created thread 85233664
thisloop = 2   threadID = 83087360 args = 2.0 -2.0 ithread = 1
Created thread 85770240
thisloop = 1   threadID = 82550784 args = 1.0 -1.0 ithread = 0
Created thread 86306816
thisloop = 7   threadID = 85770240 args = 7.0 -7.0 ithread = 1
Created thread 86843392
thisloop = 6   threadID = 85233664 args = 6.0 -6.0 ithread = 2
Created thread 87379968
thisloop = 8   threadID = 86306816 args = 8.0 -8.0 ithread = 0
thisloop = 5   threadID = 84697088 args = 5.0 -5.0 ithread = 3
thisloop = 10   threadID = 87379968 args = 10.0 -10.0 ithread = 2
thisloop = 9   threadID = 86843392 args = 9.0 -9.0 ithread = 1
```

Comment: The one thing I'm not sure I like about the above solution is that when the max number of threads are active, the 'while' loop spins away, presumably chewing up CPU cycles that could be used for something else.  Adding a 'sleep' inside the loop might be counterproductive if its length is comparable to the average execution time of a thread.  I'm not sure whether there's a way around that.

Comment: To avoid a spin-loop, you need to use thread synchronization primitives such as mutexes and semaphores.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know what either of those terms mean (I'm new to multi-threading), so I'll have to do some more homework.